# New Suunto Ambit3 and don't know how to move log data from watch to moves count

Tags: gear

I am brand new to the activity tracker watch world and can't figure out for the life of me how to transfer an activity from the log on my watch to movescount. I have everything connected and my move is not showing on moves count. Sorry if this is a basic thing, but I can't find any info in the FAQ. Can anyone help a newbie out?

Answer (score 1):

Section 6.1 [here](http://ns.suunto.com/Manuals/Ambit/Userguides/Suunto_Ambit_UserGuide_EN.pdf) shows what you should do. Once movescount is installed, it should just work.

If this doesn't work then you may have a technical issue which you will need to take up with Suunto.